# Cannot create NSSpeechRecognizer in MacOS

Tags: macos, speech-recognition

Under Mojave (Xcode 11.3.1) I create a NSSpeechRecognizer to recognize some simple command words, using:

```
 self.speech = [[NSSpeechRecognizer alloc] init];
```

Generally, MacOS is configured in French language/France region. I use english as the development language of my application. This app is built against 10.11 for compatibility reasons.

When this code runs (in the `viewDidLoad` method of the main view controller), `self.speech` returns an alloc-init'ed NSSpeechRecognizer, and speech recognition of the french words works as designed.

When I change the language/region of the computer (in System Preferences) to english/UK and restart the computer and my application (which uses a set of english words to be recognized), the same alloc/init line of code returns `nil`, while the debugger and the console show no message. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Well. The problem came from the dictation settings (For Mojave: in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Dictation) as english was not installed. It required a few minutes to download English/UK and English/US data, and now everything works fin. Except I didn't find any mean of detecting which language has been set in these System Preferences, to choose the appropriate command set.